# Deploy to user with disabled login using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, deployment, capistrano

I have the following setup on the production server:

- Root ssh is disabled
- There is user with sudo privileges that is allowed to login via ssh
- There is a deployment user created with --disabled-login

I need to deploy a rails app inside the home directory of the deployment user using Capistrano. I had to add git keys to the sudo user so that Capistrano can access git, though it seems logical to me that the deployment user must hold the keys, but I can't find the way to force Capistrano to switch user after logging in via ssh.

At the moment I got stuck at:

```
mkdir: 
cannot create directory ‘/home/deploy/myapp/shared’
: Permission denied

mkdir: 
cannot create directory ‘/home/deploy/myapp/releases’
: Permission denied
```

Sudo user can't create directory in the directory that is owned by the deployment user. I tried setting `:user` and `:use_sudo` to all possible combinations, it didn't help. I found capistrano-switchuser gem, but don't know where to place switchuser command, as the login process is not broken down into tasks.

Comment: Did you ever firgure this out?